# New Sandy Bridge microarchitecture

Tags: cpu, intel-core-i5

In regards to the new Intel Core i5-2300 processor (Sandy Bridge in general too):  Aside from it being a 32nm chip, are there other improvements?  Is this a superior chip to the older 45nm i5 750 cpu?

Comment: You probably should rephrase your question to omit anything that could be interpreted as asking for shopping advice. These questions are off topic on this site.

Answer (score 1):

In Cinebench it is 17% faster than the former i5: [source](http://en.inpai.com.cn/doc/enshowcont.asp?id=7947&pageid=7714). It also has an improved on die GPU that boasts performance that should be better than most low profile video cards. I don't have a source for the previous one and would have to test it in 3dmark before I would believe it. You should have a look at the Intel Processor comparison website [Here](http://www.intel.com/consumer/products/processors/comparison.htm) to see specific changes between this iteration of the core processors and the previous ones. For real world tests I would suggest checking out [this](http://www.tomshardware.com/reviews/sandy-bridge-core-i7-2600k-core-i5-2500k,2833-12.html) article from toms hardware it provides a bunch of PCMark Vantage benchmarks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the Sandy Bridge chips are a substantial improvement on the previous Core ix chips.

> Sandy Bridge is Intel’s latest
>   microarchitecture, and although CPUs
>   built to this new design still use the
>   familiar Core i3, i5 and i7 brand
>   names, they bring some major advances
>   over the previous generation.
>
> The GPU has been beefed up and moved
>   onto the same silicon die as the rest
>   of the CPU, making the design faster
>   and more power efficient. New
>   “advanced vector extensions” (AVX)
>   help accelerate certain types of
>   repetitive operations, promising a
>   significant boost to applications such
>   as media converters.
>
> And the Turbo Boost system has been
>   upgraded: more cores can be
>   overclocked at once, and to higher
>   frequencies than before, while a new
>   “kick-down” algorithm automatically
>   provides a brief additional boost
>   whenever the CPU load goes up suddenly
>   — such as when you open a program or
>   maximise a window.
>
> The only frustration is Sandy Bridge
>   brings a new LGA 1155 socket. It looks
>   identical to LGA 1156, but isn’t
>   compatible, so upgrading will mean
>   buying a whole new motherboard.

[**Source, with more details.**](http://www.pcpro.co.uk/reviews/processors/363982/intel-sandy-bridge)